# Recovery Behaviour Plugin not loading

Tags: ros, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Husky in Gazebo simulation. Because it is not circular in shape, rotate recovery does not help much. So I am trying to use a plugin.

The Plugin is located in my catkin_ws.

`rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core` correctly lists the following:
`straf_recovery /home/ted/catkin_ws/src/straf_recovery/straf_recovery_plugin.xml`

and here is how I have modified the `move_base.launch` file:

`<arg name="recovery_plugin" default="straf_recovery"/>`

`<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">`
`<param name="recovery_behaviors" value="$(arg recovery_plugin)"/>`

But during runtime i get the error:
`The recovery behavior specification must be a list, but is of XmlRpcType 4`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243506/recovery-behaviour-plugin-not-loading/) by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2016-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you have to add the param as below

[ { name: "backup_recovery", type: "backup_recovery_dwa/BackupRecovery" } ]

---

Originally posted by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) with karma: 190 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0